# Recreating the Google Play Newsstand menu using HTML, CSS & jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I've been searching around to no avail. The Play Newsstand and WSJ mobile apps use a nifty off-canvas approach to their menus, by taking advantage of horizontal overflow and touch swiping. I'm unsure where to start to replicate this without ugly scrollbars.

I'm guessing a standard UL menu will suffice, but how to treat it using jQuery is where I'm stuck for ideas.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image: Play Newsstand app]

[image: WSJ app]

Answer (score 0):

I know of no specific tutorial, but I'll try to point you in the right direction with how to achieve this. I'm not going to write the whole code, as I believe this is a learning curve you need to go through. I will however give you some pointers.

Here's how I would approach this.

What you'll want is to have a generic class for each segment of the page you want to be able to swipe to. Let's call this the `swipe` class. So add `class="swipe"` to the *wrapper* elements of each individual segment of the page. Let's use the first image above as your example. We have `Highlights News Business Entertainment Sport` as the tabs, so you'd make five different wrappers with the class `swipe` and give them each a unique ID so we can customise behaviour later.

So, how do we know which is active? When you first load the page, the first tab will be active. So you can specify the first tab as active with `$('#highlights').addClass('active')`. Works, but it's not very extendable. What if we want to re-order our source in the future? Or what if we add a new wrapper later? We want to account for this in advance to make it much easier to manage the page.

This is where we'd take advantage of indexing. First though you need to know how many `swipe` boxes there are. You can get this total with `var swipeTotal = $('.swipe').length`. This will return the *total* number of swipe wrappers. We can then use this to manage the current swipe, transition effects, etc.

For example, let's replace our `#first` thing above to flag the first segment as active automatically: `$('.swipe:nth-index(1)').addClass('active')`. How you then proceed to change the active `swipe` depends on the platform you're on. For mobile, you'll need to detect a swipe event and change the active `swipe` depending on which side they swipe: left or right. On desktop you can add invisible tags to detect clicks either side of the page, or map the swipes to the mouse wheel. I'd recommend the latter because this is the behaviour most users will expect in an app.

There's two ways of then keeping track of which is currently active. If you swipe right, the second tab will be active (make sure to remove `.active` from the first tab). Swiping left will make the last tab active. You can use a selector `$('.swipe.active').attr('id')` to find the *id* of the currently active tab *or*, more efficiently, you could keep a numerical counter of which tab is active. Make a variable before all of this and add or decrease the variable depending on whether you swipe left.

```
var counter = 1 // 1 is the first swipe class

$('.swipe:nth-child('+counter+')') // will select the current .swipe
$('.swipe:nth-child('+(counter-1)+')') // will select the previous .swipe
$('.swipe:nth-child('+(counter+1)+')') // will select the next .swipe
```

Make sure when the user swipes to a new wrapper that you increase or decrease this counter accordingly. To make sure you're not swiping to a box that doesn't exist add a simple conditional to reset or change the counter accordingly. For a seamless effect going above the max should reset to the first and below 1 should go to the last:

```
if( counter < 1 ){ counter = swipeTotal }
if( counter > swipeTotal ){ counter = 1 }
```

Why don't we just use numerical IDs instead? It'd be easier for the above, sure, and cut out the need of counting the swipes, but it'd remove a very key functionality: the ability to target each swipe depending on the menu above.

Adding this behaviour to the menu is easy. Simply make the target of the menu items *the same as the ID of their target swipes* to force the counter into behaving accordingly. Let's assume you have the links wrapped in a `nav`. We'll use prevent default here to stop the user's page scrolling to the bookmark in the source. For users without javascript on desktops this will also preserve key functionality; you don't want their clicks on menus doing nothing. This will take them to the bookmark, just without the fancy effects.

```
$('nav a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); // stop the targetted bookmark from loading
     var target = $(this).attr('href');
     $('.swipe.active').removeClass('active'); // remove as active swipe
     $('.swipe'+target).addClass('active'); // make the target active swipe
}
```

You can call upon a `swipeLeft`/`swipeRight` function to activate the animations on these clicks. Google's News Stand uses a lovely gliding animation. You can achieve this with `scrollTop`/`scrollLeft` or `left`/`top`/etc animations. Just make sure to always update the counter accordingly so that it's keeping track. In order to have a seemless swipe you'll need to change the positions of the next slide prior to activating the animation. For example, let's say you're on the third slide. Before you activate the swipe/scroll animation to go to the fourth slide, you'll need to position the fourth slide to the right of the third slide. You then animate all them to behave as you want and **leave** them where they end up. A lot of popular slider / tab apps like to reset their positions each time but this is trivial and pointless processing. Older tablet users will thank you for having as little jQuery to process as possible.

(Was the above not clear enough? I'll expand simply. In order to have the seamless swipe that the newsstand uses, the user needs to be under the impression that they are spinning around in a circle. Obviously they're not - that would be terribly impractical and over the top. Providing the *next* and *previous* slides animated in and out of view respectively, the effect will be achieved.)

A quick example on how to do this animation:

```
function swipeRight(){
    $('.slide:nth-index('+(counter+1)+')').css('left','100%')

    $('.slide:nth-index('+(counter)+')').animate({'left':'-100%'},300)
    $('.slide:nth-index('+(counter+1)+')').animate({'left':'0'},300)

    counter++ // because we went right
}
```

Lastly, and perhaps most importantly, you want to bring this altogether in functions that will allow you to add new segments in later **without having to modify your jQuery whatsoever**. So you'll make a `swipeLeft`, `swipeRight`, etc function that will handle the correct procedure for both animating the tabs and keeping count correctly. You could forego the counter and use numerical IDs and maintain the same functionality. This, however, is much *clearer* and easier to manage. I believe making flashy jQuery apps is a lot easier with named identifiers rather than numerical, but naturally others will disagree.

**Remember to also apply an `overflow:hidden` to the size of the viewport so that you don't get scrollbars!**

I apologise for the wall of text! I'll be happy to help further but I definitely encourage you to experiment with this yourself using my pointers - it's always fun developing a fancy sliding animated app.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate explanation, you even went beyond what I was asking for.

Perhaps I didn't explain properly, but I was just after some advice on the menu alone - so how to treat the touch and overflow of the menus. The page tabs aren't something I'd be looking to implement.